# How to use feComposite when an input is not a part of the object of the filter?

Tags: svg, css-animations, svg-filters

```
<svg>
  <style>
    #ani{
      stroke-dasharray: var(--len);
      stroke-dashoffset: var(--len);
    }
    #shadow{
      filter:url(#Blur);/*omit*/
    }
  <style>
  <script>
    document.onclick=()=>{
      document.getElementById("ani").atyle="stroke-dashoffset: 0;"
    }
  </script>
  <path id="ani" d="..." />
  <line id="shadow" x1y1... /><!--overlapped-->
</svg>
```

A simplified version of the code is shown above, I want the shadow to only appear when #ani overlap it,but if I use feComposite on #shadow, I can't specify another input of it.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to import the "ani" path into your filter using feImage and a fragment identifier. (If you also want this to work in Firefox, you will have to convert the path into a complete inline SVG within the feImage. You can look up how to do that separately.) This version should work everywhere else.

```html
<svg width="800px" height="600px">
<defs>

  <filter id="overlap-shadow" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
    <feImage xlink:href="#ani-path" x="0" y="0" result="imported-ani"/>
    <feComposite operator="in" in="SourceGraphic" in2="imported-ani" result="overlap"/>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4" in="overlap" result="blurred-overlap"/>
    <feComposite operator="over" in="blurred-overlap" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
  </filter>
</defs>

<line filter="url(#overlap-shadow)" x1="50" x2="400" y1="50" y2="50" stroke="red" stroke-width="5"/>

<path id="ani-path" d="M 0 0 L 100 50 h 100 L 300 150" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I tried your method, but THE lack of input and output made me unable to understand, could you please add it on?

Comment: Ok I made all the inputs and outputs explicit within the filter.